# How do I get my stylesheet to connect to my html file?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a project for school, and I was wondering why my stylesheet isn't linking to my HTML file, I've tried rewriting it, putting it in different places, and still nothing! Here's the code if needed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>About Me</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>About Me</h1>
<p>Hello everyone and welcome to my little website!</p>
<p>You can just call me Golden Rose<p>
<p>I play/watch and review games, movies, and tv shows (especially horror).</p>
</body>
</html>


body {
font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the path in your browsers developer tools? (Hover over the CSS link's href in the dev tools and check that it displays the expected full URL)

Comment: are you talking about `stylesheet.css` or the css part you put at the end of your exemple? (be specific in your question. Anyway, your code is correct, except that css part at the end should be inside `<style></style>` tags inside `<head>` or `<body>`

Answer (score -1):

If you can ensure the file location is correct, you may need to do a browser refresh. This can be done in Chrome by pressing control and f5 at the same time. This will clear all cache and force the stylesheet to load.

Comment: Or a browser hard refresh by pressing control, shift and f5. This clears the cache so you dont get problems with browsers loading an old file